# Cross-compiling QT interface to a Raspberry PI 3

Tags: raspbian-jessie, ubuntu, cross-compilation, qt

I'm trying to install Qt interface to a Raspberry Pi 3, which *raspbian* is the "2016-05-27-raspbian-jessie".

I didn't want to install, directly, all the packages on the raspberry so as to let more free memory. I, then, opted for a cross compilation, from my ubuntu 16.04.

To be able to do that, I followed [this tutorial](https://github.com/AlbrechtL/welle.io/blob/8fc57390bfb1f312094425a329ff52635b405c17/RASPBERRY-PI.md).

However, when getting to the cross compilation step, I've got this error about the environment setting.

Bellow is the command I typed:

```
doe@doe-Aspire-E5-573:~/raspi1/qt5$ ./configure -release -opengl es2 -device linux-rasp-pi3-g++ -device-option CROSS_COMPILE=/home/doe/raspi1/gcc-linaro-5.5.0-2017.10-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf- -no-use-gold-linker -sysroot /home/doe/raspi1/sysroot -opensource -confirm-license -no-use-gold-linker -make libs -prefix /usr/local/qt5pi -extprefix /home/doe/raspi1/qt5pi -hostprefix /home/doe/raspi1/qt5 -v
```

And here is the entire trace-back:

```
+ cd qtbase
+ /home/doe/raspi1/qt5/qtbase/configure -top-level -release -opengl es2 -device linux-rasp-pi3-g++ -device-option CROSS_COMPILE=/home/doe/raspi1/gcc-linaro-5.5.0-2017.10-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf- -no-use-gold-linker -sysroot /home/doe/raspi1/sysroot -opensource -confirm-license -no-use-gold-linker -make libs -prefix /usr/local/qt5pi -extprefix /home/doe/raspi1/qt5pi -hostprefix /home/doe/raspi1/qt5 -v
<srcbase> = /home/doe/raspi1/qt5/qtbase 
<outbase> = /home/doe/raspi1/qt5/qtbase 
Creating qmake...
make: Nothing to be done for 'first'.
Info: creating super cache file /home/doe/raspi1/qt5/.qmake.super
Command line: -release -opengl es2 -device linux-rasp-pi3-g++ -device-option CROSS_COMPILE=/home/doe/raspi1/gcc-linaro-5.5.0-2017.10-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf- -no-use-gold-linker -sysroot /home/doe/raspi1/sysroot -opensource -confirm-license -no-use-gold-linker -make libs -prefix /usr/local/qt5pi -extprefix /home/doe/raspi1/qt5pi -hostprefix /home/doe/raspi1/qt5 -v
Project ERROR: Cannot run target compiler '/home/doe/raspi1/gcc-linaro-5.5.0-2017.10-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++'. Output:
===================
/home/doe/raspi1/gcc-linaro-5.5.0-2017.10-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++: 1: /home/doe/raspi1/gcc-linaro-5.5.0-2017.10-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++: cannot create /@@p�
           @8: Directory nonexistent
/home/doe/raspi1/gcc-linaro-5.5.0-2017.10-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++: 1: /home/doe/raspi1/gcc-linaro-5.5.0-2017.10-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++: ELF: not found
/home/doe/raspi1/gcc-linaro-5.5.0-2017.10-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++: 3: /home/doe/raspi1/gcc-linaro-5.5.0-2017.10-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++: Syntax error: ")" unexpected
===================
Maybe you forgot to setup the environment?
```

As you can see, some characters are even not "readable", maybe there is some problem with the linaro file downloaded? or maybe, the problem is that my version is old enough to be obsolete?

Any help would be very welcome, thanks in advance =)

Comment: Raspbian Jessie is deprecated and has no support anymore since beginning of this year. You really should consider to use Raspbian Buster now.

Comment: Ok, That's what I understood ;)
Thank you